# SUPERUSER doesn't propagate to other region

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I use Cassandra 3.9.

I have two data centers on AWS.

Each data center contains 3 nodes as my database server.

When I created a superuser in one node by executing `CREATE USER 'hello' WITH PASSWORD 'world' SUPERUSER`, I received the following error.

```
NoHostAvailable:
```

However, interesting enough, when I execute `LIST USERS`, the user `hello` is listed as a superuser, and I can log into cqlsh using this user and password.

I can log into cqlsh in other two nodes in the same data center, but I can not log into cqlsh in any of nodes in the other data center. This is very strange to me because everything should be propagated through these two data centers. I would like to emphasize that every data user inputs propagates throughout these data centers without any problem. So why does the superuser not propagate?

When I tried logging into cqlsh in the other data center, I received the following error.

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'172.51.11.232': AuthenticationFailed('Failed to authenticate to 172.51.11.232: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level LOCAL_ONE"',)})
```

I didn't particularly change anything between these data centers.

I made sure I set `authenticator` to `PasswordAuthenticator` and `authorizer` to `CassandraAuthorizer` in every cassandra.yaml file and restarted cassandra in every node through these two data centers.

I appreciate any suggestions.

**Update:**
The following is the result of executing `DESCRIBE KEYSPACE system_auth`.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

Comment: What about the replication strategy of `system_auth`? `DESCRIBE KEYSPACE system_auth`.

Comment: I updated my post. Do you think there is anything wrong on the keyspace?

Comment: Yes, see my answer. I would keep only the first line of the output in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replication strategy of the system keyspace (keeping, among other things, the user data) is wrong:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

It should be changed to match the replication strategy of your "regular" keyspaces, at least for the datacenter part, possibly with a higher replication factor per datacenter.